# Firebase Crashlytics Console not showing crash logs

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have implemented the crashlytics as per the doc.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0&platform=android.

but still my firebase console not getting the crashes.

Attaching the firebase console and logcat.

[Firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byk9K.jpg)

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/262my.jpg)

Please help me to fix the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that you've already enabled Crashlytics debugging output. To verify that your crash report was captured, enqueued for upload and sent, try to run logcat with this filter: `adb logcat -s FirebaseCrashlytics TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler TransportRuntime.CctTransportBackend TransportRuntime.DefaultScheduler`. Look for `Crashlytics report successfully enqueued to DataTransport` message and then `TransportRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Making request to` with subsequent `TransportRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Status Code: 200`.

Comment: Hi, i couldn't see any messages like this.. already I posted the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase crash analytics generally takes 24-48 hours to show effect. If you added recently then please wait.

Comment: OMG, really? Google claims it takes up to 5 minutes (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=1&platform=android) Why does it have to take so long?

Comment: @auspicious99 not sure.......but on my personal 5 projects, each of them took a minimum of 24 hours to activated.

Comment: It is more than 48 hours now and still nothing.The crashlytics debugging output ended with `D/FirebaseCrashlytics(23841): Crashlytics report successfully enqueued to DataTransport: 603B968F001F00015D21614184AB1DFB
D/FirebaseCrashlytics(23841): Crashlytics completed exception processing. Invoking default exception handler.` more than 48 hours ago.

Comment: @auspicious99 did you check your firebase console? didn't it logged crashes??

Comment: When I wrote "still nothing", that means I checked the firebase console and it is still showing the spinning animation waiting to receive the first crash to display.